# iOS - Can I "white label" certain apps not to be auto-offloaded?

Tags: iphone, ios

I use the  "auto-offload app" feature of iOS that uninstalls unused apps on my phone to free up storage.

For the most part this is really useful, but there are some apps which I use infrequently, and if they get offloaded they need to be reconfigured to work. Example: CCTV viewer app, which needs to be re-paired with the CCTV hardware each time, which is quite a complex procedure.

Is there any way I can "white label" certain apps not to be offloaded even if they are infrequently used?

- iPhone 8, iOS 13.3.x

Comment: I just want to note here that apparently the preference to "Offload Unused Apps" may be under `Settings -> App Store` or `Settings -> General ->  iPad/iPhone Storage` (depending on the iOS version.)  Whatever the setting, you can manually offload an individual app under `Settings/General/Storage`.

Answer (score 2):

I can find no option to whitelist individual apps, which is a **great** idea. It seems to be all or nothing. I've taken to removing a lot of apps I rarely use manually, foregoing this utility, unfortunately.

Apple's official wording states: *Automatically remove unused apps, but keep all documents and data. Reinstalling the app will place back your data, if the app is still available from the App Store.*

Perhaps you should write to the developer of CCTV Viewer if the setup/pairing data is not retained when the app is off-loaded and then re-installed.

You should also go to the [Apple Feedback site for iPhone](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) and make a feature request. You won't get any reply unless you provide your email address, and they have further questions, but at least it'll get on their (very long) list of enhancement requests.